# One or more mappers failed to initialize :relationship 'post' expects a class or a mapper argument

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

'''sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class Comment->comment'. Original exception was: relationship 'post' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: )

i want to relationship between them but it shows me this error i am beginner in sqlalchemy so please solve this.
'''

```
class Posts(db.Model):
Sno = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(80),unique=False,nullable=False)
slug = db.Column(db.String(21),nullable=False)
content= db.Column(db.String(120),nullable=False)
date = db.Column(db.String(12), unique=True)
img_file = db.Column(db.String(12), unique=False, nullable=True)

class Comment(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'comment'
Sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
Name = db.Column(db.String(50),unique=False,nullable=False)
Email = db.Column(db.String(120),nullable=False)
Message = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
post_sno = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.Sno'), unique=False, nullable=False)
post = db.relationship('posts', backref=db.backref('posts', lazy=True))
date = db.Column(db.String(12), unique=True,default=datetime.utcnow)
status = db.Column(db.Boolean,default=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Comment %r>' %self.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class Posts(db.Model):
    columns = your_columns(xyz, abc)
    comment_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('comment.id'),
        nullable=False
    )

class Comment(db.Model):
    columns = your_columns(xyz, abc)
    posts = db.relationship('Posts', backref='comment', lazy=True)
```

The `relationship` should point to the class which the orm is trying to make a list from. So, the orm is trying to make a list of `Posts` for each comment. The backref allows you to reference the other side of the relationship using a `.object` notation. So, if you build a `Posts` and you want to get its `Comment` that looks like:

```
posts = Posts.get_or_404(1)
comment = posts.comment # this is what your "backref" refers to
```

As an aside, I think you probably have your relationships mixed up. I imagine that comments are a many-to-one relationship to posts, not the other way around.

If that's the case, it should be something like:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    columns = your_columns(xyz, abc)
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='post', lazy=True)

class Comment(db.Model):
    columns = your_columns(xyz, abc)
    post_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('post.id'),
        nullable=False
    )
```

Then you can get all comments for posts like this:

```
post = Post.get_or_404(1)
comments = post.comments
```

And you can get the post for each comment like this:

```
comment = Comment.get_or_404(1)
post = comment.post
```

You can read more on the [Flask SQLAlchemy doc page](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#simple-relationships).

Comment: Okay, you should mark this as answered then. Thanks.